# First element of array is al;ways null - java

Tags: java

Whenever i put the first students name in when it displays them it always comes up as null however nothing else does this.Why?

```
package school.register;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SchoolRegister {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] Students = new String[5][2];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please put in a students name.");
            Students[i][j] = Input.nextLine();
            for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                System.out.println("Please put in a students test score.");
                Students[i][j] = Input.nextLine();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Score\tName");
        display(Students);

    }

    public static void display(String x[][]) {
        for (int row = 0; row < x.length; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < x[row].length; column++) {
                System.out.println(x[row][column]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the error? What exactly is the output?

Comment: For the first student name it always outputs "Null"

Comment: Please: a) format your code propperly b) respect the Java coding conventions (methods must always begin with a lowercase letter) and c) include the exact error message in your question.

Comment: It wasnt actaully an error message, just it wasnt working to how i wanted it to and sorry i know until now to format my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] Students = new String[5][2];
        int i;
        int l = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            System.out.println("Please put in a students name.");
            Students[i][0] = Input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please put in a students test score.");
            Students[i][1] = Input.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("Score\tName");
        Display(Students);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Please put in a students name.");
Students[i][0] = Input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please put in a students test score.");
Students[i][1] = Input.nextLine();
```